# How to await execution of async in ASP.NET Core API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm using ASP.NET Core API for creating an API which I consume in client side using a React app that relies on Redux and Sagas. The point is that at one point in my client side app, I do two API calls one after the other. One is to register a new user, and the second one is to register a new company that the user specified in the form and to add the newly registered user to that organization. So it basically calls two methods in my backend.

My register function that is called first looks like this:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost("~/api/account/register")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Register([FromBody]RegisterViewModel model)
{
    var user = new MyUser
    {
        UserName = model.Email,
        Email = model.Email,
    };

    var result = Task.Run(async () => { return await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password); }).Result;
    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
           // Partially removed for brevity.
    }
}
```

And my other method that is called as part of the second API call looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]OrganizationModel model)
{
    // Partially removed for brevity.
    try
    {
        var org = _mapper.Map<OrganizationModel, Organization>(model);

        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
        if (user == null) return BadRequest(ErrorMapper.MapError("post_failed"));

        org.Admins.Add(user);

        _repository.Add(org);
        var result = await _repository.SaveAllAsync();
        if (result) return Created($"/api/organizations/{org.Id}", _mapper.Map<Organization, OrganizationModel>(org));
        else return BadRequest(ErrorMapper.MapError("post_failed"));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError($"Failed to add a new organization: {ex}");
    }
}
```

So, basically as you can see in the second method, I want to get the current user (please note that after registering the user I automatically sign in the user), and add the current user to the list of admins for the organization.

After some debugging what I noticed is that, `Register` method is called, and the like starting with `var result = ...` is called, but then the next line `if (result.Succeeded)` is not called, instead it immediately jumps to the second method shown and it continues to execute it until it reaches `var user = ...` at which point no user will be logged in and `user` will be null, so it will go out of this method and move back to the `Register` method and continue with the line `if (result.Succeeded)`. I want the whole `Register` method to execute before it moves to execute the second method. How can I wait that the `Register` method executes fully before moving to the other one?

**EDIT:**

Client side code looks like this:

```
if (!error) {
    // Partially removed for brevity.
    const user = {
        email: emailInput,
        password: passwordInput,
        confirm_password: confirmInput,
    };
    signup(user);

    const org = {
        name: newOrganizationInput,
    };
    addOrganization(org);

    this.resetState();
}
```

Comment: `Task.Run(async () => { return await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password); }).Result;` Why, why, why??? Why is that not just `await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password)`??

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I had it like you have written, but wanted to try with `Task.Run` to see whether it will continue executing the `Register` method before moving to the `Post` method. But, apparently, it doesn't, it still moves to the `Post` method.

Comment: Once you're moving your code to `async`/`await`, you should rarely *need* to manually run tasks.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I know, but somehow I need to make sure that `Register` method finishes fully, it creates the user and sign in the user, so that my other method `Post` will continue successfully.

Comment: "I do two API calls one after the other" : are you sure? can you post the client code?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto That's what I wanna achieve. My `Register` method creates a new user and then signs in the user inside the `if` statement once the registration is successful. So, I need to make sure that it fully finishes somehow before moving to `Post` method.

Comment: Please post your client code, I'm pretty sure your problem is there, not in the back-end

Comment: @tinker first, remove all those `Task.Run` and `.Result` calls. They serve no purpose other to create compilation errors. Even if you get the code to compile you'll still be blocking with that `.Result`. `await` isn't broken. If you have a different problem ask about that

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I just posted it in the edit.

Comment: That's not quite enough, what's `signup(user);` and what's `addOrganization(org);`?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Well then I need to post hundreds of lines of code. I have reducers, sagas, etc. It's a React/Redux app. But they basically make the API calls.

Comment: I understand that, but from my extremely basic knowledge of React, it's all asynchronous. Seeing the two calls one after the other makes me think you are calling asynchronous code in a non-blocking manner (something like calling two `async Task` methods without `await`ing them)

Comment: @tinker again, `async/await` isn't broken. Putting `Task.Run` on top of `await` and then calling `.Result` is meaningless. If "execution jumps" it's probably because your code *throws* and the client calls the second method even though the first failed. Or you may be calling the second method without ever waiting for the first to return

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Basically, the API calls are made like `yield apply(...)`.

Comment: @tinker people can't debug your client code telepathically. The **client** made **two** calls

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The first is not failing actually, it successfully creates a new user, but it moves to the second method, and then second method fails, and moves back to the first method to finish the creation of the user.

Comment: Again, please put an `[Authorize]` attribute to the POST, you will see that **the  client** is making the second request before it should. And that's something you have to fix on the client, not on the server

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Okay, I will try to include some blocking into the client side.

Comment: @tinker no, don't use blocking on the client side. Fix the code on the client side so that React *reacts* when a response arrives. You should post a new React question, since this isn't an ASP.NET Core issue - apart from that missing `Authorize` call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You await the execution of an asynchronous method using the `await` keyword.
However, your problem is not with the backend but the client.

`fetch` / AJAX calls in JavaScript are asynchronous. So it really don't matter if the backend awaits or not, the client will still hit both endpoints without waiting.

You are probably doing something like:

```js
fetch('/api/account/register', { ... });
fetch('/api/organizations', { ... });
```

The fetch methods execute asynchronously and return a promise.
What you need to do is:

```js
await fetch('/api/account/register', { ... });
await fetch('/api/organizations', { ... });
```

or

```js
fetch('/api/account/register', { ... }).then(x =>
  fetch('/api/organizations', { ... });
);
```

Comment: We don't have a concrete example to work with, so I would refrain from answering, but the OP commented that they are using `yield apply(...)` for the calls. Not sure how that works though